# SQL query based on results of other query - why is it slow?

Tags: mysql

I'm deleting records from one table based on other table's status and generating long response time from server.

Basicly if theres a `name` with `status = 'p1'` query shold `delete` records off another table. The problem is I thint that `log_player_login` has thounsands of `WHERE timestamp > '$timeHuman' AND status = 'p1'`

What am I doing wrong?

```
DELETE FROM pstone_cuboids
WHERE owner NOT IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT(name)
  AS name
  FROM log_player_login
  WHERE timestamp > '2013-01-01 00:00:00' AND status = 'p1'
);
```

From:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "having a lag"?

Comment: Long response time from server.

Comment: . . `lag` has a specific meaning in SQL because it is the name of a function.  I sort of guessed that's what you meant.  A better way to phrase it would be something like "Why is it taking such a long time?" or "Taking too long".

Comment: I knew someone would point that :) Question edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until the most recent versions of MySQL, `not in` with a subquery was rather inefficient.  I would suggest replacing it with `not exists` and adding an index:

```
DELETE FROM pstone_cuboids
WHERE not exists (SELECT 1
                  FROM log_player_login lpl
                  WHERE lpl.timestamp > '2013-01-01 00:00:00' AND lpl.status = 'p1' and
                        lpl.name = pston_cuboids.owner
                 );

create index log_player_login_owner_status_timestamp on log_player_login(name, status, timestamp);
```

The index should have all three fields and the last one needs to be `timestamp`.

Comment: What about upgrading mysql? I do have `MySQL: 5.5.33`

Comment: Why to add an index? Never used one, how it will impact my data?

Comment: @Ultra . . . I think the fixes on the subquery came in version 5.6x.  You want the index to improve performance.  That is primarily what indexes are for (they also enforce unique constraints).

Comment: You said to replace `not in` with `not exists` yet cant see that in your code.

Comment: @Ultra . . . Oops, fixed.

Comment: Ive updated to 5.6.x and it's still long response time (my old query). In phpmyadmin I can see: `mysql version: 5.6.15` `web server mysql version: MySQL: 5.5.35` - is that what you suggested updating?

Comment: @Ultra . . . I missed that the columns being compared have different names.  Fixed.

Comment: Syntax error `SELECT FROM pstone_cuboids
WHERE not exists
 (
  SELECT name
  FROM log_player_login lpl
  WHERE lpl.timestamp > '2013-01-01 00:00:00' 
  AND lpl.status = 'p1' 
  AND lpl.name = pston_cuboids.owner
 );
`

Comment: @Ultra . . . Do you mean something like `select *`?

Comment: This index - it's should be created just once?

Comment: After creating index, changing to `not exists` and removing `DISTICNT` as it's completly useless here it's working blazing fast. Thanks!